# Add facebook SDK in Phalcon

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, phalcon

I'm trying to load Facebook SDL into my project but at the moment with no success

here is my bootstrap dispatcher:

```
$di->set('Facebook', function() use ($config) { 
    return new Facebook(array( 
        'appId' => $config->facebook->appId, 
        'secret' => $config->facebook->secret, 
        'fileUpload' => $config->facebook->fileUpload, 
        'allowSignedRequest' => $config->facebook->allowSignedRequest, )); 
});
```

the loader looks like this(in code is before dispatcher):

```
$loader->registerDirs( array( 
    DIR . $config->application->controllersDir, 
    DIR . $config->application->pluginsDir, 
    DIR . '/app/library', DIR . $config->application->modelsDir, 
    DIR . '/app/facebook', ) 
)->register();
```

where facebook files were put in /app/facebook, /app/library, /app/library/facebook. I tried multiple ways of including the files.

I called the facebook class like this: `$user = $this->Facebook->getUser();` in IndexController and error which i received is: Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /mylongpath/public/index.php on line 142

I assume the problem is the loader by not sure what and why. Please help me with this situation.

The rest of project is "INVO" tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bad guess, but if you are with invo and based on [index.php](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/public/index.php), your `app` is one level up related to your `public/index.php`, making it:

```
$loader->registerDirs( array( 
    __DIR__ . $config->application->controllersDir, 
    __DIR__ . $config->application->pluginsDir, 
    __DIR__ . $config->application->modelsDir,
    __DIR__ . '/../app/library', 
    __DIR__ . '/../app/facebook') 
)->register();
```

Make sure to use `__DIR__`, not `DIR`, unless you've set it up as an actual var / cost before.

+ [did composer got out of fashion?](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk#usage)

```
"facebook/php-sdk": "@stable"
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/geass/Phalcon-Facebook-Library

i did smt like that , maybe it is what u ar trying to do.